# Scapy: How to dissect C union?

Tags: python, c, scapy

I want to use Scapy to dissect the packet defined by the following C structure:

```
struct {
    int type;
    union {
        int int_value;
        char byte_value;
    } data;
} MyPacket;
```

The message is constituted of the `type` field which specifies what is the type of the data field: 0 and `data` is an `int` (coded on 4 bytes), 1 and it is a `char` (coded on one byte).

It is important to note that the union has a size equal to the size of its largest member.
In my case the size of the data will always be 4 bytes even if `type` is 1 and `data` a `char`.

Here is the code I created:

```
from scapy.all import Packet, IntEnumField, IntField, ByteField, ConditionalField

types = {
    0:"int",
    1:"byte"
    }

class MyPacket(Packet):
    fields_desc = [
        # Type indicator
    IntEnumField("type", 0, types),
        # Union
    ConditionalField(IntField("int_value", 0), lambda pkt: pkt.type==0),
    ConditionalField(ByteField("byte_value",0), lambda pkt: pkt.type==1)
        ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "My packet with type int:"
    p1 = MyPacket("\x00\x00\x00\x00" # type = int
                  "\x00\x00\x00\x10" # int_value = 16
                  )
    p1.show()
    print "\nMy packet with type char:"
    p2 = MyPacket("\x00\x00\x00\x01" # type = byte
                  "\x10"             # byte_value = 16
                  "\x00\x00\x00"     # Unused.
                  )
    p2.show()
```

And the output:

```
My packet with type int:
###[ MyPacket ]###
  type      = int
  int_value = 16

My packet with type char:
###[ MyPacket ]###
  type      = byte
  byte_value= 16
###[ Raw ]###
     load      = '\x00\x00\x00'
```

As you can see, in the case of `data` being a `char`, some data of the union is left unconsumed.
This can be troublesome if another field would follow the data field. So my question is:
Is there a way to consume all the bytes of a C union with Scapy?

Comment: Using structures or unions for serialization should be avoided in if possible. Be prepared to deal with alignment, endianness and padding issues (like now). Ideally runtime data is serialized to byte array manually, using dedicated functions to convert variables to bytes and back.

Comment: The design of the `union` itself is the core problem here. Such a union doesn't make sense in C, so it will not make sense in Python either. You should avoid "variant" types in C, their presence is an indication of a fundamentally flawed program design.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks. This is one thing I was not aware of. I will keep this in mind when I develop C programs. However, in this particular case, I do not have the permission to change the definition of the messages.